# In the last episode of "Your Lie in April", what was enclosed in the envelope?

Tags: your-lie-in-april

This is where the letter by Miyazano Kaori is being read out. The English subtitles said,

> P.S. I'm enclosing something that I've always treasured.
>   If you don't want it, feel free to tear it up and throw it away.

[image: The enclosed object]

I can't understand Japanese; I don't know if she was being more descriptive there. All I can see is a part of a picture of two females in skirts, and one or two little kids. One of them appears to be an adult or an older girl, and the other, a young girl. But I can't recall such a scene in the series. What exactly was she talking about, and what was the picture that was enclosed?

If the voiced description in Japanese was insufficient, does the manga shed more light on it?

Comment: picture, from when the first recital. its the "lie" in april.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the end of the episode, the photo that you mention can be seen sitting on Kousei's desk. Kaori treasured it because it was probably her only photo containing her and Kousei or even her only photo of Kousei.
[image]

It is a photo of **young Kousei and Kaori plus another unnamed girl**(most possible  Kaori's friend), probably after one of Karima's contests. Kaori was, most likely, there for her friend which probably participated in the said contest. There is a chance that this is the contest in which Kaori saw Arima for the first time, the one that motivated her to start pursuing music.

Comment: Please allow me to humbly confirm that all your assumptions are correct. The scene can actually be seen in the special volume of your lie inapril: Coda. The volume has been partially adopted into an OVA episode as well. The pic was taken by accident and young Kaori loved it so much she tried to preserve the picture using plastic wrap.